# How to make a child widget that stays at the same screen position when the parent widget is moved?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I am experimenting with creating a child widget that stays at the same screen position even when the parent widget is moved. This should generate the impression that the parent widget "views" an underlying scene. The following code illustrates what I want:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QPalette, QPainter
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class Child(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Child, self).__init__(parent)
        pal = QPalette(Qt.white)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setPalette(pal)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.fillRect(25, 25, 50, 50, Qt.red)
        painter.end()

class Parent(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Parent, self).__init__(parent)
        self.child = Child(self)
        self.child.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100)

    def moveEvent(self, event):
        diffPos = event.pos() - event.oldPos()
        self.child.move(self.child.pos() - diffPos)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    parent = Parent()
    parent.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 300)
    parent.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, it flickers! I think this is due to the fact that I end up painting twice. Since the child widget stays at the same position, it does not actually need to be redrawn. I have experimented with `WA_StaticContents`, `QEventFilter`, etc to try to tell Qt that it should not redraw the child widget, but was not successful.

Comment: I do not think it **stays** at the same position. This is result of the negative movement you perform for the child widget. What if you try to use a single widget that paints its "child" content?

Comment: why is the benefit of the parent-child relationship then?

Comment: @vahancho: Yes, I presently achieve this by moving the child widget in the opposite direction when the parent is moved. I was thinking I could suppress the paintEvent to avoid the flicker, but was not successful.

Comment: @UmNyobe: The child interacts with the parent in ways that are not relevant for my question.